# Json input of a stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure with a JSON in input ,Is it possible to use the JSON  as input for a stored procedure? how could i do that ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [warm].[stored _table]  
 (
  @Json NVARCHAR(MAX)
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  BEGIN TRY
       BEGIN

        WITH JsonToTable AS 
        (
            SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@Json) WITH (
                [type] [nvarchar](100), 
                [source] [nvarchar](38), 
                [time] [nvarchar](28), 
                [ID] [varchar](50) '$.data.ID',
                [RegionCode] [varchar](10)'$.data.RegionCode'
                [DueDate] [datetime2](7)'$.data.DueDate',
                [SchedulStartDate] [datetime2](7)'$.data.SchedulStartDate',
            
                
            )
        )

        MERGE [warm].[table] AS TARGET 
        USING JsonToTable AS SOURCE 
        ON (TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET 
        TARGET.[RegionCode]                 = (SOURCE.[RegionCode]
        TARGET.[DueDate]                 = [dbo].[ufn_cast_string_to_date](SOURCE.[DueDate])
       ,TARGET.[SchedulStartDate]        = [dbo].[ufn_cast_string_to_date](SOURCE.[SchedulStartDate])
      
        
        
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT 
                (
                 [SourceID]
                ,[ID]
                ,[RegionCode]
                ,[DueDate]
                ,[SchedulStartDate])
            VALUES
                (
                 1
                ,[ID]
                ,[RegionCode]
                ,[dbo].[ufn_cast_string_to_date](SOURCE.[DueDate])
                ,[dbo].[ufn_cast_string_to_date](SOURCE.[SchedulStartDate])
     );                 

    END
    END TRY
   
    END
```

I Want to execute it with the request below  :

```
    DECLARE @return_value int
    EXEC    @return_value = [warm].[usp_upsert_warm_table]
    @Json = N'{
"type" : "table",
"source" : "informations",
"time" : "2018-04-05T17:31:00Z",
"id" : "A11-111-111",
"data" : {"
 "ID":"123-56",
 "RegionCode":"2",
 "DueDate":"2020-13-14T10:54:00",
 "SchedulStartDate":"2020-12-14T10:54:00" 
  }'}
```

I get this Message Error :

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 480.**

Comment: Yes, the JSON is not valid. This is a valid JSOn input - `{"type" : "table",
"source" : "informations","time" : "2018-04-05T17:31:00Z","id" : "A11-111-111","data" : { "ID":"123-56", "RegionCode":"2", "DueDate":"2020-13-14T10:54:00", "SchedulStartDate":"2020-12-14T10:54:00" }}`

Comment: JSON is not valid. If you have a table to insert then use a table valued parameter instead, if it's just one row then use a bunch of parameters properly. And not sure why you got a `TRY` with no `CATCH`. Also I'd love to know what `ufn_cast_string_to_date` does more than standard date conversion functions

Comment: JSON works with SQL Server, but it works poorly. Everything has to be quoted, it won't have integers without quotes, it gets picky about arrays and square braces. If you can, avoid using SQL Server as your json store. It is a headache. An option is to pass the json to a dataframe in Pandas, and use json_normalize to get a clean table. Just my 2 cents from experience.

Comment: Function to convert date from string -- datetime

Comment: for the information in  input should i insert them in a table?

Comment: @Zhorov HE GIVES me now this error : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @nada Well, what date is `"DueDate":"2020-13-14T10:54:00"`? It must be `"DueDate":"2020-12-14T10:54:00"`.

Comment: DueDate":"2020-13-14 10:54:00 even without T  ts not working :-

Comment: It's a datetime2

Comment: yes,"DueDate":"2020-12-14T10:54:00"  thnaks, but still not working

Comment: @Charlieface yes it s to convert time from varchar to datetime2 , but it did ot work with me :(

Comment: How about you give use the code for that function, and explain why you couldn't use `CONVERT(datetime2, myDate, 126)` Also you should declare the JSON `[DueDate] nvarchar(20) '$.data.DueDate'` then convert afterwards

Comment: Many thanks i figure that and i post an answer! that right i forget to declare my input as a varchar ..that solved my probleme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Valid input :

```
 DECLARE    @return_value int
 EXEC   @return_value = [warm].[usp_upsert_warm_table]
    @Json = N'
 {  
  "type" : "table1",
  "source" : "",
  "id" : "A111-111-11",
  "time" : "2020-12-14 10:54:00",
  "data" :{
  "ApplicationID":"INFORMATIONS",
  "ID":"157faf1657c-100",
  "RegionCode":"2",
  "DueDate":"2020-12-14 10:54:00",
  "SchedulStartDate":"2020-12-14 10:54:00"}'}
```

For my input date : 2020-12-14 10:54:00 i deleteed the T in the middle
for my S.P : I change the type of My variables from datetime To varchar  :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [warm].[usp_upsert_warm_table]  
...
    
            [ID] [varchar](50) '$.data.ID',
            [RegionCode] [varchar](10)'$.data.RegionCode'
            [DueDate] [varchar](40)'$.data.DueDate',
            [SchedulStartDate] [varchar](10)'$.data.SchedulStartDate',
        
  ....
```